# Get data-value of each individual div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a couple of plugins to animate progress bars using JavaScript.

I'm setting the data value of each one in HTML to avoid defining it in JavaScript each time.

```
<div class="progress-circle" data-value="0.65">
```

I want to get the data value to animate and stop at that value each time but the code I have at the moment stops all of them at the 1st divs value.

```
    var el = $('.progress-circle'),
    inited = false;

    el.appear({ force_process: true });

    el.on('appear', function() {
      if (!inited) {
        el.circleProgress({ value: el.attr('data-value') });
        inited = true;
      }
    });

    $('.progress-circle').circleProgress({
        size: 80,
        startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 2,
        lineCap: "round",
        fill: { color: "#64B46E" } 
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
    $(this).find('.inner').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2)+ '%');
});
```

How can I get this to use each divs unique data-value attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('your-div').each(function() {
   //do something with $(this).data('value');
   //other way to get is $(this).attr('data-value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as `$('.progress-circle')` returns an array of elements try looping through each element and this might work :)

```
var arr_el = $('.progress-circle');
$(arra_el).each(function(i,el){

   var inited = false;
   el.appear({ force_process: true });
   el.on('appear', function() {
    if (!inited) {
      el.circleProgress({ value: el.attr('data-value') });
      inited = true;
    }
   });
   $(el).circleProgress({
    size: 80,
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 2,
    lineCap: "round",
    fill: { color: "#64B46E" } 
   }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
     $(this).find('.inner').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2)+ '%');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all your elements, you're only doing something to the first one at the minute. jQuery has `each()`. Sans jQuery (ES2015 syntax), for comparison:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.progress-circle'))
     .forEach(pCircle => someFunctionThatRunsYourSideEffects(pCircle))
```